# Аналог типа LARGEINT в Firebird

Tags: python, firebird, sql

При выполнении sql запросов выдало ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ThirdTask\connect.py", line 118, in <module>
    cur.execute(s)
ProgrammingError: (-607, 'isc_dsql_prepare: \n  Dynamic SQL Error\n  SQL error code = -607\n  Invalid command\n  Specified domain or source column LARGEINT does not exist')
```

Какой аналог типа LARGEINT существует в Firebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIGINT

Answer (score 0):

**INT64** , я давал линк на типы, повторяю еще раз [типы данных в Firebird](http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=tipy_dannyx)

[@msi](/users/2339/msi) в **FireBird** нет **BIGINT**

Comment: @savro, http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-bigint.html

Comment: Спасибо не знал, хотя и задач под огромные числа не стояло